# Change zsh history color

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion, terminator

I'm trying to change the colour of the autocomplete (from history) so that it doesn't match my input color (maybe same color less opacity..). Here's a pic:

[image]

Is this possible? (I'm using Terminator, if that helps at all..)

Comment: I believe so. Check `man zshzle`, and specifically the `region_highlight` array. I don't know the details of correctly specifying the regions involved to provide an answer at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I presume you are talking about `zsh-autosuggestions` and not [`zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) (which is an awesome plugin, by the way; you should try it. :)

Secondly, out of the box, inline suggestions provided by `zsh-autosuggestions` are colored "bright black", which should usually work out as dark gray.

The behavior you're seeing is likely caused by your terminal incorrectly being reported to Zsh as not supporting more than 8 colors. Thus, Zsh rules that "bright black" is an invalid value for `region_highlight` (since it falls outside of 8 color range) and discards it.

Note, however, that the terminal does not directly report the number of colors it supports to Zsh. Rather, it sets the `$TERM` variable, which is then looked up in the `terminfo` database to determine the terminal's capabilities. It looks like Terminator needs some special handling for this: https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/TerminatorFAQ#why-am-i-having-problems-with-terminfocurses

Answer (score 1):

Anyone getting here wondering why suggestions are not light-colored should also check the following:

I you are using `zsh-autosuggestions` and `zsh-syntax-highlighting` make sure you have activated the lastest *in last position*. Otherwise, they make a mess and suggestions appear as default prompt.
Activation list:

```
plugins=( [plugins...] zsh-syntax-highlighting)
```